# What is path made of?

Tags: landscaping

I've often seen paths in parks that are made up of a yellow looking sort of material. It doesn't get your shoes muddy and appears to let rain soak right through.

Does anyone know what it is and how are these built?

Example image of what it looks like
https://www.flickr.com/photos/eutouring/38400363916

Comment: They have paths like that round the Eiffel Tower in Paris, France - I examined it closely whilst there but couldn't decide what it was made of - certainly there seemed to be a high element of sand involved, possibly some crushed stone; the paths were quite dusty on that very hot day, and the dust was the same colour as the material of the path. You can get a similar effect (minus the dust) with light coloured gravel/resin paths - they can be made with a water permeable construction.